# how to output image file from database drupal 7?

Tags: database, drupal, drupal-7, output, drupal-modules

I have created testing module that will upload image and outputting it to my page. but, i can't seem to output my image file from my database. pls help! here's my code

```
      <?php

function database_ex_menu(){
$items = array();
$items['database-ex'] = array(
    'title' => 'My Database Form',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'access arguments' => array('submit database_ex'),
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('database_ex_form'),

    );
     return $items;
  }

 function database_ex_form($form, $form_state){

$form['myimage'] = array(
    '#type' => 'file',
    );


$form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Add item'),

    );


return $form;
```

}

```
     function database_ex_form_submit($form, $form_state){
    $fe_id = db_insert('example')
    ->fields(array(
            'myimage' => $form_state['values']['myimage'],
        ))
    ->execute();

    drupal_set_message(t('Your entry has been added'));
 }
```

This function supposedly will output my image file inside a div.

```
  function database_ex_submission(){

 //What to do From here!
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you need to fetch all the data  from your table, in that the image uri will be saved

use `file_create_url($uri)` to create full URL from the uri you have saved in  database.

```
$result = db_query("SELECT myimage FROM example");
$records = $result->fetchAll();

foreach ($records as  $value) {
    $uri = $value['url'];
    $url = file_create_url($uri);
}
```

In $url you will get the full path to the image.

Comment: in the $uri variable whats the value of the url?

Comment: it will be like "public://uploads/imagename.png"

Comment: how do i render all image from my $uri folder?

Comment: All image will have a uri value in your database (table name will be like field_data_field_YOURFIELDNAME), you will get the uri from the table. Better to write a query join with node table.